# Why is QListView blank after setRootIndex?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, model-view

I have a tree like model (which iff non-empty has always height 2). In a tree view, the data is correctly displayed. However, I want to display the data in two ListViews, `dupFilesOverview` and `dupFilesDetailview`:
`dupFilesOverview` is showing the elements at depth 1, while `dupFileDetailView` should show the children of the of the element selected  in the overview.

To do this, I'm currently using the following code (where dm is my model):

```
ui.dupFilesOverview->setModel(&dm);
ui.dupFilesDetailview->setModel(&dm)
QObject::connect(ui.dupFilesOverview->selectionModel(), &QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged, [&ui, &dm](const QItemSelection& selection) {
   QModelIndex index  =selection.indexes().first();
   ui.dupFilesDetailview->setRootIndex(index);
});
```

Via some qDebug output,

```
qDebug() << index << dm.data(index, Qt::DisplayRole) << dm.hasChildren(index) << dm.data(index.child(1,0), Qt::DisplayRole);
```

I  verified that the index I've obtained is indeed the one that I want: It is valid and has the expected children. From the documentation, I would expect `dupFilesDetailDetailview` to now show the children of my model at the specified index.  Alas, it stays blank instead. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: About the only thing that you're missing is a test case that reproduces the problem. You're doing something wrong, but it's fairly hopeless if you don't show the code where you're doing it :( The code that you show here is correct. You'd need to include the entire code for the model, and any setup or data population if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it turned out to be an embarrassing off-by-one error in the model: The `parent` function returned the wrong index.